# Default App Icon Shape visible behind my Icon

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am facing a very weird problem. After my app completion, I added an Icon for my iPad app. Works fine. But as I am having Icon design some what different, some part of the iPad's default icon background is visible.

[image: Check here the screen shot]

If you see, the black part behind is visible, look very ugly. I want to remove this somehow. How to overcome this?

Please help.

Comment: you can't use transparency in app-icons

Comment: I think its not possible, you can not add transparent background to your icons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Apple Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html):

> Ensure that your icon is eligible for the visual enhancements iOS provides. You should provide an image that:
>
> - Has 90° corners (it’s important to avoid cropping the corners of your
>   icon—iOS does that for you when it applies the corner-rounding mask)
> - Does not include a drop shadow
> - Does not have any shine or gloss
>   (unless you’ve chosen to prevent the addition of the reflective
>   shine)
> - Does not use alpha transparency

So.. Dont use transparency!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. However, you change the background of your icon from transparent to black.

Comment: what if the user have a white background it will still be ugly.

Answer (score 1):

App icons cannot use transparency. They must have a solid background colour. What you can do is make the background of your icon black, but this will still show up on coloured backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting "Icon already includes gloss effect" in xcode summary screen? This is probably because gloss effect blends with black giving you this look

Hope this helps

Cheers

Comment: this will only effect the gloss on top of the icon.